# Java Calculate time until event from current time

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate the amount of time until the start of a soccer game.

This is what I know:

- I have the time of an event:**2016-08-16T19:45:00Z**
- I know the string format of it is "**yyyy-M-dd'T'h:m:s'Z'**"
- I know the timezone is "CET".

I want to be able to calculate the difference from the current time to this date in days.

This is what I have tried:

```
    String gameDate = "2016-03-19T19:45:00'Z'"
    DateFormat apiFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd'T'h:m:s'Z'");
    apiFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
    Date dateOfGame = apiFormat.parse(gameDate);

    DateFormat currentDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd'T'h:m:s'Z'");
    currentDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(userTimezone));
    Date currentDate = apiFormat.parse(currentDateFormat.format(new Date()));

    long lGameDate = dateOfGame.getTime();
    long lcurrDate = currentDate.getTime();
    long difference = lGameDate - lcurrDate;
    Date timeDifference = new Date(difference);

    String daysAway = new SimpleDateFormat("d").format(timeDifference);
    Integer intDaysAway = Integer.parseInt(daysAway);
```

You are probably wondering why I don't just get the date of the game (8) and subtract the current date (19). I don't do that in the edge case that the current date is the 29th and the game date is the 3rd of the next month.

Comment: No, using normalization before subtraction is customary. The approach looks generally right, and it's not clear what your question or problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating the difference between two Java date instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Comment: I'd just like to note that your date string ends with `Z`. This means the timezone is UTC, not anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing/ using `TimeUnit`:

## Example:

```
final String gameDate = "2016-03-19T19:45:00Z";
final SimpleDateFormat apiFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US);
apiFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
final Date dateOfGame = apiFormat.parse(gameDate);
final long millis = dateOfGame.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(dateOfGame.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis());

final String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
System.out.println(hms);
```

This will print the output:

> 72:57:34

72 hours, 57 minutes and 34 seconds from now until gameDate

Comment: I like this method the most. Thank you! Much easier

Comment: I believe you should subtract `hours * 60` from millis before getting minutes

Answer (score 7):

Nobody has yet provided a Java 8 `java.time` answer...

```
    String eventStr = "2016-08-16T19:45:00Z";
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME;
    Instant event = fmt.parse(eventStr, Instant::from);
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    Duration diff = Duration.between(now, event);
    long days = diff.toDays();
    System.out.println(days);
```

Comment: For java < 8, `joda`s `Duration` can be used instead http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( 
    Instant.parse( "2016-08-16T19:45:00Z" ).atZone( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) ), 
    Instant.parse( "2016-08-23T12:34:00Z" ).atZone( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) ) 
);
```

## Define “days”

There are two ways to count a number of days. Your Question is not quite clear which you intended. This Answer shows example code for both ways.

- Calendar-based days by date
  Apply the intended time zone to determine the dates of the start and the the stop. A date is determined by zone, as for any given moment the date varies around the globe being “tomorrow” towards the east while “yesterday” to the west depending where you sit. For example a few minutes after midnight in Paris France a new day while still “yesterday” in Montréal Québec.
- 24-hour chunks of time
  If you consider only generic days of 24-hour chunks of time while ignoring anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST), then you get the total number of seconds between the beginning and ending moment and divide that by 24-hours. In this approach we ignore the calendar and its dates.

Example of the differences: Start late Monday night, an hour before midnight. Stop an hour after midnight on Wednesday morning. For 24-hour chunks that total of 26 hours is a single day. But by calendar dates  that would two elapsed days, having touched three calendar days.

Why two days if we touched three? Date-time work commonly uses the Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The modern way to do this work is with the java.time classes rather than the troublesome old legacy date-time classes (`Date`, `Calendar`, etc.).

The [Answer by dcsohl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36045249/642706) is correct but could be shorter. No need to be explicit about the `DateTimeFormatter` as the input string is in one of the standard ISO 8601 formats used by default.

> I know the string format of it is "yyyy-M-dd'T'h:m:s'Z'"

As part of the ISO 8601 standard, the `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu` and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
String startInput = "2016-08-16T19:45:00Z" ;
String stopInput = "2016-08-23T12:34:00Z" ;
```

Parse as `Instant` objects. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant start = Instant.parse( startInput );
Instant stop = Instant.parse( stopInput );
```

> I know the timezone is "CET".

Time zone is irrelevant to parsing the strings. But time zone does matter in terms of calculating elapsed days if counting by calendar dates rather than by 24-hours per generic day.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` or `CET` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );
```

Adjust both our start and stop moments into that time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = start.atZone( z );
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = stop.atZone( z );
```

The java.time framework provides two classes for spans of time:

- [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) for years-months-days
- `Duration` for hours-minutes-seconds

The `Period` class takes a pair of `LocalDate` objects, date-only values without time-of-day and without time zone. We can extract `LocalDate` objecs from our `ZonedDateTime` objects. Remember that date is determined by zone. So it is crucial that we adjusted our UTC values into `ZonedDateTime` objects.

```
Period p = Period.between( zdtStart.toLocalDate() , zdtStop.toLocalDate() );
```

You can interrogate that `Period` for the number of years and months and days of that span of time.

If you want a total number of days, use the [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( zdtStart , zdtStop );
```

The above is for calendar date-based counting of days.

If you want to count by generic chuncks of 24-hour periods, use the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class as shown in the [Answer by dcsohl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36045249/642706).

```
Duration.between( start , stop ).toDays()
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could simply take the result from `long difference = lGameDate - lcurrDate;`, which is the difference in milliseconds, and convert to whatever unit you like.

For example, in days: `int days = difference/1000/3600/24`;

Comment: that way you can get one day error. example: if you have 23:00 on 1st and 01:00 on 3rd that is 26 hours difference and 2 day difference. and if you have 20:00 on 1st and 22:00 on 2nd that is the same 26 hours difference but only 1 day

Comment: @celezar that was just an example, you can chose whatever time unit and the approximation/error you want as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String gameDate = "2016-03-19T19:45:00Z";
    DateFormat apiFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    apiFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
    Date dateOfGame = apiFormat.parse(gameDate);

    long now = new Date().getTime() / (3600000 * 24);
    long game = dateOfGame.getTime() / (3600000 * 24);
    System.out.println(now - game);
}
```

This will work because you are getting number of full days since epoch for date of game and now and just need to find difference. Other solutions will have errors in border cases.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your date format is wrong. It should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'` instead of `yyyy-M-dd'T'h:m:s'Z'`.

Also, your `gameDate` String should end in `Z` and not `'Z'`.

You can easily get the difference in days by just calling the `getTime()` function on current and given dates. You don't even have to format the current date.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String gameDate = "2016-03-19T19:45:00Z";
    DateFormat apiFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    apiFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
    Date dateOfGame = apiFormat.parse(gameDate);

    long difference = new Date().getTime() - dateOfGame.getTime();
    System.out.println((double)difference / (3600000d * 24d));
}
```

You can do the rounding on the result if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `difference` contains the time difference in milliseconds. To convert those milliseconds to days, hours, minutes, seconds I recommend you to use the `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` class.

Example:

```
final long durationMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(difference);
final long durationSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(difference)
            - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(durationMinutes);
final long durationMillis = difference- TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(durationMinutes)
            - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(durationSeconds);
final String durationString = String.format("%d min, %d s, %d ms", durationMinutes, durationSeconds, durationMillis);
```