# MongoDB And Java Driver (TimeStamp Help)

Tags: java, mongodb

I need to create a timestamp with interval of 1 day this is the right way ?

```
long day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;     
Date date = new Date();
Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime() + day);
```

And the other question is how can i format the timestamp to get the formated time like this:

> 22 hours and 31 minute and 1 seconds lefts.

Comment: Please keep distinct questions to separate posts, and please try to be more concise with your question title..  "Add a day to a timestamp" may be more appropriate

Comment: Still waiting for useful answers not like this

Comment: It wasn't an answer, it was a community review. The community reviews questions to ensure they are of good quality.

Comment: Then dont comment .. i ask this question for useful answers to solve this dude

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just store `System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)` as a long into your collection.

A good example to format your time is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042954/java-calculate-time-until-event-from-current-time).

Comment: But i want to make a delay like this: You already buy this sword please wait 1 day to buy another