# show remaining minutes instead of hours

Tags: android, date, time, notifications, sleep-mode

I need your help to
show remaining minutes instead of hours

15 minutes instead of 15:30

**Sample:**
time left to start reservation: 15 minutes

```
 private Notification getNotification(Date countdownEnds) {
    DateFormat timeFormat = countdownTimeFormatFactory.getTimeFormat();
    String countdownEndsString = timeFormat.format(countdownEnds);
    String title = resources.getString(R.string.countdown_notification_title);
    String text = resources.getString(R.string.countdown_notification_text, countdownEndsString);

    PendingIntent tapIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setTicker(title)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(tapIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(false);

    return builder.build();
}




   public DateFormat getTimeFormat() {
        return android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context);
    }
```

kod:[code](https://github.com/OldSneerJaw/sleep-timer/blob/master/SleepTimer/src/main/java/com/oldsneerjaw/sleeptimer/CountdownNotifier.java)

Comment: _15 minutes instead of 15:30_. That doesn't make sense as far as I understand from your question 15 is the hour, not the minute

Comment: Is it so that 15:30 is the time when the countdown ends (or 3:30 PM) and when the time is 15:15, so there are 15 minutes remaining, you want to display “15 minutes”? You can get a lot of inspiration from [Java Calculate time until event from current time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042954/java-calculate-time-until-event-from-current-time). Please search for more interesting and helpful questions and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barebones solution:

```
    long remainingMillis = countdownEnds.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
    long remainingMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(remainingMillis);
    String countdownEndsString = String.format("%d minutes", remainingMinutes);
```

For a nicer solution use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, for the calculation of the minutes:

```
    long remainingMinutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(
            Instant.now(), DateTimeUtils.toInstant(countdownEnds));
```

In this case also see if you can get rid of the use of `Date` completely since that class is long outdated, and all the functionality and more is in `java.time`. In the last snippet I am using the ThreeTen Backport (see explanation and links below) and its `DateTimeUtils` class. For anyone reading along and using Java 8 or later and still not having got rid of the `Date` class, the conversion is built into that class, so it is slightly simpler yet:

```
    long remainingMinutes 
            = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(Instant.now(), countdownEnds.toInstant());
```

You may also want to look into the `Duration` class of `java.time`.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.